# Prove that it is possible to build a local countable basis

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topological space and $x\in X$ from where $\mathcal{B}(x)$ is an countable local basis of $x$. I want to show that it is possible to construct a countable local basis $\mathcal{D}(x)=\{D_{1}, D_{2}, \dots \}$ such that $D_{1}\supseteq D_{2} \supseteq D_{3} \supseteq \cdots$

Well, we can start by considering a countable local basis of $x$, namely $\mathcal{B}=\{B_{1}, B_{2} , B_{3}, B_{4}, \dots, B_{n}, \dots \}$, as this basis is local then for all $U^{\text{open}}\subseteq X$ (s.t. $U\in N(x)$ i.e. $U$ is in a neighborhood of $x$), there exists $B_{j}\in \mathcal{B}$ s.t.

$$x\in B_{j}\subseteq U$$

Otherwise we could say that $X$ is first-countable.

but, how is the construction of the base from this information? I was thinking that maybe the intersection of the elements of the given base can work, but I don't see it clearly, any suggestions? appreciate it!

Comment: You're on the right track with using finite intersections. What do you know about $B_1\cap B_2$? $B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite intersections work fine. They're all nonempty, open neighbourhoods of the point $x$ and they're decreasing in size. If $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ it must contain $B_n$ for some $n$ so in particular it contains $\bigcap_{j=1}^nB_j\subseteq B_n$, so we obtain the local basis property too.

Comment: This was something I was just thinking about, thanks for clarifying!